# Access @Component Beans initialized by IoC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I am trying to access a bean, which is annotated with `@Component` and initialized by Spring IoC. I have an abstract class which should return the correct concrete child class in a static method.

But I always facing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

I tested to `@Autowired` my OrderFactoryFinland in one of my `@Controller` classes, and it is correctly initialized by Spring IoC with all DAO fields.

So in my opinion, it should be somehow possible to access this Singleton instance in the static method?

**Concrete sub class:**

```
@Component
public class OrderFactoryFinland extends OrderFactory {
    @Autowired private TenantDao<Material> materialDao;
}
```

**Abstract super class:**

```
public abstract class OrderFactory {
    @Autowired protected UserService userService;

    public static OrderFactory getOrderFactory(Company company) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
        Integer companyNumber = new Integer(company.getCompanyNumber());

        if (companyNumber.equals(SystemGlobals.COMPANY_NUMBER_FINLAND)) {
            return context.getBean(OrderFactoryFinland.class);
        } else if () {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.xxx.yyy.order.fin.OrderFactoryFinland] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace

Comment: post your application context file (or at least relevant parts)

Comment: Which parts are you interested in?

Comment: Component scan is activated for all needed packages. Singleton bean is properly created but I am not able to access it within the static method. Maybe it is a problem of compile order..

Comment: Are you sure that the static method is called after the context is created?

Comment: I call the method after the users clicks on a button. This action is definately after context creation, but I am not sure at which time the static method is compiled.

Comment: It is also interesting, that I can access those beans which are directly defined in applicationContext.xml, but not those which are defined with @Component.. But I do not wanna define the factory beans in my applicationContext.xml. It must be possible with an annotation solution. Otherwise I have to look for another solution.

Comment: That is weird indeed. Unfortunately I don't have any more suggestions...

Comment: Okay thanks for help. I can recreate my problem in every other class. I can just access those beans which are defined in applicationContext.xml. So it is not related to the static method. It seems that beans, created by IoC with annotations are not accessable over ApplicationContextProvider. But where are they stored?

Comment: Are you perhaps using a hierarchy of contexts?

Comment: No only one root context.

Comment: Could you also post ApplicationContextProvider?

Comment: Did you scanned the package? <context:component-scan> or @ComponentScan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access the application context with the `@Autowired` annotation and not with a custom `ApplicationContextProvider` which implements `ApplicationContextAware`.

Now I have acccess to all my beans. So it seems that this was a timing problem.

```
private static ApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
public void setContext(ApplicationContext context) {
       OrderFactory.context = context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` suggests, the error occurs because Spring fails to find the `OrderFactoryFinland` bean. Since it has been annotated with `@Component`, I guess that you intend to use component scanning to fetch it? Make sure that you have included the correct package. This applies regardless if you are using XML based configuration `<context:component-scan ... >` or Java based config `@ComponentScan(...)`.

On a higher level, all Spring beans are by default [Singelton Scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes), which means that there is only one shared instance of each bean in Spring's application context that gets dependency injected. Springs way of doing this is based on object instances which means that you should use *instance* methods (as opposed to static class methods) for your logic. The reason for this approach is that this allows Spring to add proxies for various reasons (caching, security, etc) in a simple, consistent manner.